Error while copying content to a stream" when uploading large GPKG file to an API using WPF application
I am trying to send a large GPKG file to an API using a WPF application, but I encounter the following exception:
Error while copying content to a stream.
What I have tried:
I have verified that the API URL is correct and works for smaller files.
I ensured that the selectedFilePath points to the correct GPKG file.
Observations:
The exception is thrown when the file size is large (e.g., several GBs).
For smaller files, the upload works as expected.
Questions:
Why does this error occur for large files?
How can I fix or handle this issue to upload large files using HttpClient in a WPF application?
`private async Task UploadFileAsync(string fileType)
// Get the API URL from the TextBox
string apiUrl = ApiUrlTextBox.Text.Trim();

// Validate the URL
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiUrl))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid API URL.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    return;
}

try
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(selectedFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                content.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream), "file", Path.GetFileName(selectedFilePath));

                // Log the request details
                MessageBox.Show($"Uploading to: {apiUrl}\nFile: {Path.GetFileName(selectedFilePath)}", "Upload Info", MessageBoxButton.OK);

                // Send the file to the API
                var response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);

                // Log the response status code
                MessageBox.Show($"Response Status Code: {response.StatusCode}", "Response Info", MessageBoxButton.OK);

                // Check if the response is successful
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("File uploaded successfully.", "Upload", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                }
                else
                {
                    string errorMessage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    MessageBox.Show($"File upload failed. Status Code: {response.StatusCode}\nError: {errorMessage}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (HttpRequestException httpEx)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"HTTP error occurred: {httpEx.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
}
catch (IOException ioEx)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"File error occurred: {ioEx.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"An unexpected error occurred: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
}

}
`
